# Cloud function generating thumbnails doesn't overwrite old thumbnail with the same name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm using cloud functions to resize and generate thumbnails for uploaded images in Firebase Storage. On the first upload the thumbnails are generated but i also want to be able to edit those images while keeping the same name.
This is how i'm doing it :

I upload an image with this function on the client :

```
    uploadImage (imageFile, folderName, imageName){
         const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
         // need to prefix image name with "slot_"
         storageRef.child(`${folderName}/slot_${imageName}`).put(imageFile)
    }
```

Thumbnails are then generated with this cloud function :

```
export const generateThumbs = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async 
    object => {
const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket)
const filePath = object.name;
const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);
const slotSizes = [64,250]

const temporaryDirectory = join(tmpdir(), `thumbs_${fileName}`);
const temporaryFilePath = join(temporaryDirectory, 'source.png');

// avoid loop includes only images
if (fileName.includes('thumb_') ||
    !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
    return false;
}

await fileSystem.ensureDir(temporaryDirectory);

// original file in temp directory
await bucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: temporaryFilePath
});
const slotUploadPromises = slotSizes.map(async size => {
        const thumbName = `thumb_${size}_${fileName}`;
        const thumbPath = join(temporaryDirectory, thumbName);

        await sharp(temporaryFilePath).resize(size, size).toFile(thumbPath);

        return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
            destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
            metadata: {
                contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            }
        })
    });


await Promise.all(slotUploadPromises)
// removes temp directory
return fileSystem.remove(temporaryDirectory);
```

So if i call `uploadImage(appleImage, 'MyImages', 'test')` i'll have in my storage folder 3 images (naming IS important):

- slot_test
- thumb_250_slot_test
- thumb_64_slot_test

At this point if i call again `uploadImage(avocadoImage, 'MyImages', 'test')` i'd expect to have in the storage the same "naming structure" but with the updated image in place of the old ones, so the new thumbnails should just overwrite the old ones. What actually happens is that the "base" image gets updated while both thumbnails don't. Ending up with :

- slot_test              (*displaying the **UPDATED** image*)
- thumb_250_slot_test    (*displaying the thumbnail of the **OLD** image*)
- thumb_64_slot_test     (*displaying the thumbnail of the **OLD** image*)

I've logged the cloud function extensively, no errors are thrown from the function during execution, thumbnails are created normally and the firebase console also updates the *creation date* of the thumbnails but i still get the old thumbnails image. I've tried removing the temporary directory using `fs-extra emptyDir()`, i've tried to remove every single thumbnail first (via client) and then uploading again with no luck.

EDIT : Found a solution to my problem by **NOT** creating any temporary folder or temporary files and using sharp pipeline instead. That said i'm still missing the underlying problem in the code above. I'm quite convinced that, for whatever reason, the function didn't remove the temporary folder and that was generating problems whenever i tried to overwrite the images. This function works :

```
export const generateThumbs = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket)
const filePath = object.name;
const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

// metadata file
const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
}

if (fileName.includes('thumb_') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
    return false;
}

if (fileName.includes('slot')) {
    // array of promises
    const slotUploadPromises = slotSizes.map(async size => {
        const thumbName = `thumb_${size}_${fileName}`;
        const thumbPath = join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbName);
        const thumbnailUploadStream = bucket.file(thumbPath).createWriteStream({ metadata });

        const pipeline = sharp();

        pipeline.resize(size, Math.floor((size * 9) / 16)).max()
            .pipe(thumbnailUploadStream);

        bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
               thumbnailUploadStream
               .on('finish', resolve)
               .on('error', reject));
    });
    await Promise.all(slotUploadPromises)
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to verify that the images are not what you expect?  Please be specific.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry in advance for the trivial example: If i upload image A naming it "apple" i end up with 3 images named respectively apple, thumb_250_apple, thumb_64_apple. Then i upload image B but i still want to name it "apple". Now i still have apple, thumb_250_apple and thumb_64_apple in my storage but the 2 thumbnails are from image A and not Image B, i can also see from the storage console that the creation date of the thumbnails is brand new but still the wrong image is returned. I edited the post since i found a solution but i'm still missing the problem in the original code

Comment: Same here, the thumb images links are pointing to the old images. The curious thing is that removing the GoogleAccessId parameter from the url, it points to the new thumbnail. @DougStevenson can you please have a check?

Comment: My code is similar to your first function code where we use `fs-extra`. I think there is some problem with overwriting of files in the temporary directory. I am even not sure whether it removes the temporary directory even though logging inside the callback function works. I changed `const temporaryFilePath = join(temporaryDirectory, 'source.png');` to `const temporaryFilePath = join(temporaryDirectory, fileName);` and it seems to be working fine for me. Did Sharp pipeline solve your issue?

Comment: @Debiprasad yes i've been using Sharp pipeline as explained in the edited part of my post for over an year now and it solves this problem, so that probably means that as you already said the problem is either the temporary directory or the temporary file created in it